# How to make a function inside a list change a variable outside of a list

Tags: python

First of, I am sure that this is a repeat question so i'm sorry, but I couldn't find anything. Also keep in mind I am very new to coding in general hence the quite dumb question
so if I have something like

```
a = 1
def fun():
    a = a + 1
fun()
```

is there a way to make it so that if I run this a would be equal to 2?

Answer (score 5):

Use `global`. Like this:

```
a = 1
def fun():
    # make a a global variable here
    global a
    a = a + 1
fun()
print a
```

OUTPUT:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with global variable a.

```
a = 1
def fun():
    global a
    a = a + 1
```